# Bigint on PostgreSQL 8.3

Tags: postgresql, bigint

I have a users table with a primary key uid of data type bigint.

I don't understand why I get the error : "Minteger out of range" when trying to add a user with uid = 100000349053153.

This should work (according to the doc: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype.html)

Comment: Way too little information. How are you adding the user? What is the exact statement you're issuing? Are you doing this programmatically? If so, what language, with what library version? Show us the exact code you're using. You've given us part of an error message, but I'm pretty sure it's not complete. Paste the _full_ message and any other relevant data surrounding it.

Comment: Sure. This the query : http://gist.github.com/627669

Comment: And the error: ERROR C22003 Minteger out of range Fint8.c L1205 Rint84:

Comment: Are you using Rails and ActiveRecord? This looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449665/using-activerecord-and-rails-to-insert-data-into-postgresql-database-get-this-err . Your table spec is probably incorrect, either you're not really using a bigint on uid, or another field is declared wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Nicholas and Adam.

The problem was tied to my confused use of Rails.

I was wrong to think that rake db:reset recreates the database from the migration files.
I had the correct migration files but rake db:reset was using the wrong information provided by schema.rb

If you want to store Facebook ID, use (inside your migrations):

```
t.integer :uid, :limit => 8
```

You can also add an index:

```
add_index :users, :uid, :unique => true
```

And if you want to recreate your Rails database from scratch use:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW the following works just fine for me:

```
CREATE TABLE bigintexample
(
  id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT pk_bigintexample_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO bigintexample (id) VALUES (100000349053153);
```